# GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx equivalent for windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-xp, console-application, backwards-compatibility

I know that kernel32.dll does not offer this newer function which seems to have a few extras, namely the modification of the color table, is there any way to get the values that are not in CONSOLEBUFFERINFO but are in CONSOLESCREENBUFFERINFOEX (other than just the registry)? and if so, where are they? I have searched a bit for this but found nothing, and its not like windows 7 consoles don't use the same old stuff xp ones do... and it seems funny that the fullscreen supported check is included in 7 and not xp since more often than not in 7 it isnt supported at all unless your using the VGA low-res mode. Any help would  be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[James Brown](http://www.catch22.net/sourcecode) has implemented function [SetConsolePalette](http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/source/files/setconsoleinfo.c).

It works for Windows 2000 and above by sending undocumented message WM_SETCONSOLEINFO, and is designed to do what you are looking for.